# Need help in finding a basis for a subspace defined by a function

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been given a set defined as follow:
set W = {x(t): x(t) = c1cos(bt)+c2sin(bt), where c1,c2 are arbitrary constants, and b is a fixed constant}
I have to find a basis for that set and justify why it is a basis.

The basis for this function is given by 
basis = { cos(bt) , sin(bt)}
My justification is because the function x(t) can be formed through any linear combination of those two elements in the basis

Am i right in considering those two elements as vectors that can appropriately form a basis or am I approaching this problem the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are approaching this problem the right way; but, you have not actually shown that $\{\cos(bt),\sin(bt)\}$ forms a basis. All that you have shown is that its span is the entire set.

In order for it to be a basis, you need more: you need to show that $\cos(bt)$ and $\sin(bt)$ are *linearly independent*! That is, you must show that $\alpha\cos(bt)+\beta\sin(bt)$ is the $0$-function if and only if $\alpha=\beta=0$.

Also, be careful: for most values of $b$, this is fine... but what about when $b=0$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes perfect sense.